# Sass returns "Error: ("primary": #0075dd !important, ...) isn't a valid CSS value." when dynamically creating a new map

Tags: list, dictionary, sass, partials, dart-sass

Whenever I run `sass --watch src/sass:dist/css` I got this error from the command line

> Error: ("primary": #0075dd !important, "secondary": #6b7a93 !important, "sucess": #1eaf3e !important) isn't a valid CSS value.
>
> > $map-theme-colors-rgb: create-map($map-theme-colors, convert-to-rgb, "value") !default;
> >                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Here's some of the code snippet.

#### _functions.scss

```
@function create-map($map, $callback-func, $args...) {
  $_created-map: ();

  @each $key, $value in $map {
    $_args: ();
    @each $arg in $args {
      $_args: append(
        $_args, if($arg == "key", $key, if($arg == "value", $value, $arg))
      );
    }

    $_created-map: map.map-merge(
      $_created-map,
      meta.call(meta.get-function($callback-func), $_args...)
    );
  }

  @return $_created-map;
}
```

#### _variables.scss

```
$map-theme-colors: (
  "primary":    $primary,
  "secondary":  $secondary,
  "sucess":     $sucess
) !default;

$map-theme-colors-rgb: create-map($map-theme-colors, convert-to-rgb, "value") !default;
```

I hope you could help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. I hope this will help those who are also struggling with the same problem.

When you use the color module:

```
@use "sass:color";

$color: "#ffbbcc"
$important-color: "#ffbbcc" !important;

// Sample function
@function toRGB($value) {
  @return color.red($value), color.green($value), color.blue($value)
}

// $color is passed as "#ffbbcc" without the quotes
// and no problem.
$color-in-rgb: toRGB($color); 


// but $important-color is passed as "#ffbbcc !important" without
// the quotes and throws an error because while #ffbbcc is a valid
// CSS color in hexadecimal, !important is not!
$important-color-in-rgb: toRGB($important-color);
```

So the solution was to remove the `!important` in my variable declarations:

```
$blue: "#0000ff"
```

Like so, and instead place it on my map:

```
$some-color-map: (
  "blue": $blue !important
);
```